# Prove the operator $f$ is normal with the expression of the operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, adjoint-operators, normal-operator

> When is $f$ a normal operator? Given that $f$ is defined as $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}+c \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{x})$ being the notation $(,)$ the inner hermitian product between two vectors, $c\in \mathbb{C}$ a constant, and $(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})\neq 0$.

I successfully found the expression of $f^* (\mathbf{x})$, which is  $f^* (\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}+\overline{c}\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{x})$ so with this I should be able to solve the question since normal operators satisfy that $ff^* =f^*f$ so then by doing the multiplication I get: $$ff^* =(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x})+\mathbf{x}\overline{c}\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{x})+\mathbf{x}c\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{x})+c\overline{c}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{x})$$ But how am I supposed to even operate this? It seems like something out my touch

---

**EDIT:** *Example of a problem that uses* $ff^*$ as a product of $f$ and $f^*$: Under what conditions of the self-adjoint operators $a$ and $b$ is $f$ a normal operator? Given that $f=a+ib$

*Solution from the book*: To prove $f$ is normal, we can use the definition $ff^*=f^*f$ so we have $$ff^*=(a+ib)(a-ib)=(a-ib)(a+ib)=f^* f$$ $$a^2+b^2+i(ba+ab)=a^2+b^2+i(ab+ba)$$ which concludes that $ab=ba$ for $f$ to be normal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, note that this is the identity operator in the case that $c = 0$, which means that $f$ is normal.

For the remaining cases, one thing that you can do to make the problem easier is note that $f$ is normal if and only if $g = \frac 1c(f - \operatorname{id})$ is normal. That is, it suffices to determine when the operator
$$
g(\mathbf x) = (\mathbf v,\mathbf x) \mathbf u
$$
is normal. As you have correctly found, $g^*$ is the map given by $$
g^*(\mathbf x) = (\mathbf u, \mathbf x) \mathbf v.
$$
Now, it's easy to look at the two compositions of these two operators. We have
$$
(g \circ g^*)(\mathbf x) = (\mathbf v,(\mathbf u,\mathbf x) \mathbf v)\mathbf u = (\mathbf v,\mathbf v)(\mathbf u, \mathbf x)  \mathbf u\\
(g^* \circ g)(\mathbf x) = 
(\mathbf u,(\mathbf v,\mathbf x) \mathbf u)\mathbf v = (\mathbf u,\mathbf u)(\mathbf v, \mathbf x) \mathbf v
$$
So, when are these two ouputs identical? Note that the the outputs of $g \circ g^*$ (i.e. the range of $g \circ g^*$) consist of multiples of $\mathbf u$, while those of $g^* \circ g$ are multiplies of $\mathbf v$. It follows that $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ must be multiples of each other.

Indeed, $\mathbf u,\mathbf v$ being multiples of one another is also a sufficient condition: for the trivial case that $\mathbf u$ or $\mathbf v$ is zero, $g$ is the zero-map and hence normal. Otherwise, if we take $\mathbf u = \alpha \mathbf v$ for some $\alpha \in \Bbb C$, then plugging into the above formulas for $g \circ g^*$ and $g^* \circ g$ yields
$$
(g \circ g^*)(\mathbf x) = \bar \alpha \alpha (\mathbf v, \mathbf v)(\mathbf v, \mathbf x)\mathbf v = (g^* \circ g)(\mathbf x).
$$
Thus, $g$ is normal if and only if the set $\{\mathbf u, \mathbf v\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: why is $gg^*$ a composition of $g^*$ into $g$ and not a product $g$ times $g^*$, I have always thought it was a product. So it is a composition of both functions but then in the matrix form it is a product of the two matrices $FF^+=F^+F$, right?

Comment: Correct. A multiplication of two marices corresponds to a composition of the underlying operators

Comment: That's nice to know, thanks, but I still have a few problems in my books where they use $ff^*=f^* f$ as a product... Mhm maybe is it because in that problem they define $f$ as $f=a+ib$ where $a$ and $b$ are also operators, so then $f$ is **not** in terms of any vector $\mathbf{x}$ unlike in this problem? It's really weird that I have 2 versions of $ff^*=f^*f$ on my book and here

Comment: @Acedium20 In the context of operator theory, it is common to write $fg$ to represent the composition $f \circ g$. Note that it does not literally make sense to multiply $f$ and $g$ (in the case where $g = f^*$); $f(\mathbf x)$ and $g(\mathbf x)$ are vectors, so the "product" of vectors $f(\mathbf x)g(\mathbf x)$ is not-defined. Note that the **inner-product** of two vectors is written as $(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)$, never as $\mathbf x \mathbf y$

Comment: I get what you are saying but if you could please look at my edit to the post where my book uses $ff^*$ as a product, I'm a little bit confused now, why does my book do it like that? Is there 2 definitions?

Comment: @Acedium20 In this context, $ab$ refers to the composition $a \circ b$ of the two operators. As I said, it's common to write $ab$ to represent this composition; in a sense, we're pretending that $a$ and $b$ are matrices.

Comment: surely $ab$ can be $a\circ b$, but I still can't grasp the idea on how we are literally **multiplying** the expressions $f$ and $f*$ to solve the problem? How is that a composition?

Comment: What makes composition look like multiplication (i.e. what makes it distribute in the same way that multiplication would) is the linearity of the operators of interest. In particular, we have $a \circ (b + c) = a \circ b + a \circ c$ because for every input $\mathbf x$ to $b$ and $c$, we have
$$
[a \circ (b + c)](\mathbf x) = a(b(\mathbf x) + c(\mathbf x)) = a(b(\mathbf x)) + a(c(\mathbf x)) = [a \circ b + a \circ c](\mathbf x)
$$
The expansion of $ff^*$ is merely an application of this pattern as well as the fact that $(b+c)\circ a = b\circ a + c\circ a$.

Comment: Okay that wraps it all, it was really confusing me since $(a+ib)(a-ib)$ seemed like the usual multiplication but it actually isn't as you showed, thanks!